Is it possible to put an image into glass jar to get a peach compote visible inside the glass jar

I have tried to put image by mapping. I created another cylinder inside the outer cylinder then I selected inside cylinder and used mapping. But it’s not quite working.

hello could you please share your file?

First thing is to separate faces inside the glass where you will add the sticker material
And create a seam (the red line) so you can UV unwrap this specific area:

Select these faces and assign a new material to it (I called it sticker), so our cup has two materials, glass material and sticker material.

For the sticker node, we are going to mix:

Glass for the front faces (points inside the cup)
Texture for the back faces (points outside of the cup)

The setup is like this:

If your glass material is more complicated than just a BSDF, you can resort to this answer to make use of the same node groups (instead of duplicating a complex material): Can you use another material as input to material nodes in cycles?
(You could also have an entirely different material, like the back of the sticker material, if you like)
Finally, adjust the UVs properly so the texture fits ok on the sticker area:

The result:

